# Is there a way to tell TypeScript to exclude a module when generating a declaration file?

Tags: typescript

We have a library that includes some modules intended for internal-use only (common util functions required by other modules).

We want to discourage other parties from taking dependencies on these internal-use-only modules by excluding those modules from our .d.ts file.

Is there a way to prevent the TypeScript compiler from listing certain module should in the .d.ts file it generates?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the behavior of module resolution by using [path mapping](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping):

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "mod": ["node_modules/@types/mod/index.d.ts"]
    }
}
```

p.s : don't try `exclude` or `typeRoots`, they won't do it for you

Comment: How would this modify the output of the .d.ts file to hide/remove/obfuscate the specified modules and their members?